# How can I to specific the css rules for Chrome and IE in my HTML page or in SCSS file?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser-detection

I want to specific that the web browsers as chrome, opera, firefox use specific css file and the browsers as IE (from version 7 to 10) using another css files.

How can I to specific this??

Thanks everyone for your help! merry christmas!

Comment: What features is IE 7 through 10 not handled properly that you would need to load a different stylesheet? Conditional comments are generally the way you would go about loading a special stylesheet for IE 9 and below, but they were deprecated in IE 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IE conditional comments such as this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
<![endif]-->
```

So you could use something like this:

```
<head>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 10]>
        <link href="iestyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

You can learn more about them [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: Hi friend!, I need to specific that css rules for IE browsers but that this CSS rules can not to be used by another browsers (by example chrome, firefox and another), this condition not have the 'ELSE' syntax ??? Let me now about this, thanks for you help!.

Comment: IE 10 *does not* support Conditional Comments.

Comment: @FranklinSarmiento Yes if you do basically this: `<!--[if !IE]> -->CODE HERE<!-- <![endif]-->` But as Jonathan said it will not work for IE 10

Comment: Thanks everyone for your helps, I can to fix my index.html page with  this.